# iOS: AutoLayout a dynamic number of items

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I'm trying to recreate the view shown below. The difficulty for me is that some of these elements will have a different number of instances.

[image]

- First item is a UILabel with variabel multi lines. There will always be axactly one of this item.
- UIImageView. This there can be zero or one item of.
- UIButton zero or more (at least up to 3-4).

### How to achieve this?

What would be a best practice to achieve this? I had one idea to use UITableView and just put each element in a table view cell. But it feels like a bit hacky solution. Especially since I then have to remove the default styling of the table (borders and padding).

Another solution is to maybe use a UICollectionView with only one column.

Third solution is to build on the autolayout solution I have, and achieve it with a lot of if statements and for-loops. This seems like a bad solution.

**So how would I achieve this (using best practices)?** And is it generally a bad idea for instance to use UITableView for pure layout purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UIStackView and inside it another one for every item with zero or more instances

Add when you want to append say a button to the buttons stackView use this

```
btnsStackView.addArrangedSubview(btn)
```

same for UILabels and UIImageViews

Check this it may help

```
   for i in 0...5
    {
        let headerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height))
       if(i % 2 == 0)
       {
         headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }
        else
       {
          headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        }

        self.stttq.addArrangedSubview(headerView)

    }


    let headerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height))

    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    self.stttq.insertArrangedSubview(headerView , at:0)
```

Comment: Thank you, forgot about the stack view. Will look into it now. :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason to create nested StackView's rather than just `func insertArrangedSubview(UIView, at: Int)` to insert the element at the right place?

Comment: No, but I prefer it so distribution is always Equally